# Comprobar que la fecha es correcta Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo que comprobar que la fecha que INTRODUCE un usuario es correcta.
Tiene que tener el patrón dd/mm/yyyy.

Lo que no consigo hacer es comprobar que la fecha sea válida (30/02/2008) o (33/10/2018), por ejemplo.

```
 validDates() {
        let okey: boolean = true;

    try {
        // Se coge la fecha y se descompone con /
        const [d, m, y] = this.filterDateStart.split('/');
        // Sino encuentra las / fallará
        if (!d || !m || !y) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        // Sino eran números fallará
        if (isNaN(d) || isNaN(m) || isNaN(y)) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        // Sino cumple la longitud fallará
        if (d.length < 2 || m.length < 2 || y.length < 4) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        // finalmente creo el objeto date con los datos, resto 1 al mes.
        // 02 "Febrero" lo cogería como Marzo.
        let date: Date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
    } catch (error) {
        okey = false;
    }
    return okey;
}
```

Mi intención es cuando se cree una fecha que no sea válida, reviente el constructor de la clase Date, pero no revienta y crea el 30 de febrero como si tal cosa....

Comment: Por favor revisa el siguiente post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072720/typescript-parse-string-dd-mm-yyyy-to-date

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas fácil de validar fechas es intentar crearlas y comprobar si el constructor te dice si es una fecha inválida:

```js
let stringFecha = "32/10/2018";
const [d, m, y] = stringFecha.split('/');
// cambiamos al estandar de fecha yyyy/mm/dd (de otra forma no te podrá convertir un string a fecha de forma apropiada)
const dateConversion = new Date(`${y}/${m}/${d}`);
console.log((dateConversion == "Invalid Date"));
```